# AngularJS: Assign default value for binding value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a dashboard with live update, so after $http call when a db returns null object i want to assign default value as zero

```js
 $scope.SAP=0;
$http({
   method: 'GET',
            url: 'getTilesDataForPrjectReport.do',
  }).then(function(response){
     if(response.data.proj==='SAP'){
     $scope.SAP=response.data;
    }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div style="height:20%; background-color:#ff9e97;">
 <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileRed"> {{SAP.red}}</p>
 <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileAmber">{{SAP.amber}}</p>
 <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileGreen">{{SAP.green}}</p>
 </div>
 <div style="height:18%; background-color:#ff8a81;">
 <p> Total Projects : {{SAP.totalProj}} </p>
 </div>
```

If SAP is not in response data, i need to display 0 in all SAP bindings,
even if i assign 0 to $scope.SAP, it's not reflecting in html. I know it could be done with ng-hide with another `<p>` tag, but what's the simplest solution

Comment: could you paste your json response here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    <div style="height:20%; background-color:#ff9e97;">
        <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileRed"> {{SAP.red || 0}}</p>
        <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileAmber">{{SAP.amber || 0}}</p>
        <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileGreen">{{SAP.green || 0}}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="height:18%; background-color:#ff8a81;">
        <p> Total Projects : {{SAP.totalProj || 0}} </p>
        </div>
     (or)
 //define $scope.default = 0;
<div style="height:20%; background-color:#ff9e97;">
        <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileRed"> {{SAP.red || default}}</p>
        <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileAmber">{{SAP.amber || default}}</p>
        <p id="colorPalletDashboardTileGreen">{{SAP.green || default}}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="height:18%; background-color:#ff8a81;">
        <p> Total Projects : {{SAP.totalProj || default }} </p>
        </div>

<!-- end snippet -->

I think, you can try this
or
```

I think you can try this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your html should be under the context of controller, where you are fetching a data and assigning to `$scope.SAP`.

You could use number filter there which will provide you `,` separated formatting too.

```
{{SAP.red | number}}
```

[**Sample Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/et6CB2UKiSB8n6nKnpqx?p=preview)

Comment: not working..i guess you need to use double pipe like below answer

Comment: @VigneshRajarajan `||` means `OR`, `|` means filter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `$scope.SAP = 0`, you can assign

```
$scope.SAP = {"red": 0, "amber": 0, "green": 0, "totalProj": 0}
```

or any default value.

Comment: when the number of scope objects and it's properties increase in future, it will be hard to do it. anyway thanks